# How Should I Fully Remove The LP

Tags: cpp-ethereum

My project is fail few months ago, and i removed the LP today, and i found there is some earned LP is not withdrawable.

Can somebody guide me how to fully withdraw it?

[image: How to withdraw the balance]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One of my friends gave me this answer when I asked him the same question, so I will share my knowledge with you. If you try to remove all the LP (liquid petroleum) from an area, you will need to use an appropriate absorbent material to soak up any remaining liquid.

This can be done with sawdust, kitty litter, or any other absorbent material. Once the area has been thoroughly saturated, you will need to dispose of the absorbent material properly. After that, you should vacuum the area to remove any remaining traces of LP.

Finally, you should thoroughly clean the area with a degreaser or detergent to remove any residual contamination.